# SHGetDriveMedia and synchronization

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, operating-system, delphi-xe2

To recognize a media i use `SHGetDriveMedia`; 
on the second parameter I pass `pdwMediaContent` for reference and the api 
insert the type of content. 
However, the recognition is done asynchronously. How can I know when the api 
has finished the recognition?

Comment: What makes you thing it is asynchronous? The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762178(v=vs.85).aspx) just says it returns the value.

Comment: for example when i introduce a bluray into drive, it take some time before the effective media recognition takes place; the function returns immediately but the second parameter is populated a little bit later.

Comment: @supercim That cannot possibly be true. You are asserting that the parameter is modified after the function returns. That cannot be the case.

Comment: @Supercim I expect it returns immediatly as it returns a cached result, only updated when the shell does its own check in the background, giving you a new value when you call it again.

Comment: @Deanna And what if the pointer refers to some location on the stack that is no longer valid when Windows decided to update it? No, what Supercim is claiming is clearly incorrect.

Comment: @Deanna Yes it is possible generally but clearly since the documentation does not call it out, it's not what happens here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not asynchronous. When you call it right after putting the disk in the drive, it's in "sniffing phase", trying to determine what method of autoplaying the disk should be used. There are several detection phases that can be returned in the [ARCONTENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761371%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flags when the function returns:

```
ARCONTENT_PHASE_UNKNOWN (0x00000000)
  Introduced in Windows Vista. AutoPlay is searching the media. The phase of the 
  search (presniff, sniffing, or final) is unknown.

ARCONTENT_PHASE_PRESNIFF (0x10000000)
  Introduced in Windows Vista. The contents of the media are known before the 
  media is searched, due to the media type; for instance, audio CDs and DVD movies.

ARCONTENT_PHASE_SNIFFING (0x20000000)
  Introduced in Windows Vista. AutoPlay is currently searching the media. Any 
  results reported during this phase should be considered a partial list as more 
  content types might still be found.

ARCONTENT_PHASE_FINAL (0x40000000)
  Introduced in Windows Vista. AutoPlay has finished searching the media. Results 
  reported are final.

ARCONTENT_PHASE_MASK (0x70000000)
  Introduced in Windows Vista. A mask that denotes valid ARCONTENT_PHASE values.
```

This seems to indicate (based on the text with `ARCONTENT_PHASE_FINAL` above) that you should expect to need to call this function more than once, until you receive that value in the flags returned, at which point you can check the other values in the flag for disk type.